# Flipping Axes of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ridgeline-plot

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(label=c("yahoo","google","yahoo","yahoo","google","google","yahoo","yahoo"), year=c(2000,2001,2000,2001,2003,2003,2003,2003))
```

How is it possible to produce a thermal plot like this one:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
theme_set(theme_ridges())
ggplot(
  lincoln_weather, 
  aes(x = `Mean Temperature [F]`, y = `Month`)
  ) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(
    aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 3, size = 0.3
    ) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("#0D0887FF", "#CC4678FF", "#F0F921FF"),
    name = "Temp. [F]"
    )+
  labs(title = 'Temperatures in Lincoln NE')
```

How can I flip the plot axes, i.e. having year as the x axis and the label in y axis?

Comment: change the values in `aes()` to match with the data frame: `ggplot(
  df, 
  aes(x = year, y = label)
) ...`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, simply use `coord_flip()`. See `ggplot2` [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_flip.html). To make things neat, rotate the axis labels using `axis.text.x` and reorder the months LTR using `scale_y_discrete`:

```
ggplot(
    lincoln_weather, 
    aes(x = `Mean Temperature [F]`, y = `Month`)
) +
    geom_density_ridges_gradient(
        aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 3, size = 0.3
    ) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        colours = c("#0D0887FF", "#CC4678FF", "#F0F921FF"),
        name = "Temp. [F]"
    )+
    labs(title = 'Temperatures in Lincoln NE') +
coord_flip()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1))+
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(lincoln_weather$Month)))
```

Now this seems a bit weird, why `scale_y` and not `scale_x`? it appears that `ggplot` first constructs the plot elements and only then flips, rotates, applying styles and so on, and as the months are originally on the y axis, you need to use `scale_y_discrete`.

If your data has now significant order, then you can obviously skip the whole `scale_y_discrete` thing.

Comment: Just a note: as of `ggplot2` 3.0.0 last year, the notation `..x..` isn't deprecated, but is encouraged to be replaced with `stat(x)`. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#new-features-1

Comment: Agreed, but this is his/her own code. I've just made some additions. `..x..` ain't my style.